# How to make text label regular font (not bold) in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm building a form using Bootstrap.  Some of the fields are read only so the value is displayed a text (not an input field).

I want the label on the left to be bold and the value on the right to be regular (not bold).

Here's the code and a screenshot ... what is the correct way to have the value on the right display as regular font (not bold)?

[screenshot of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AreT.png)

```
  <form id="saveEntityDefForm" class="form-horizontal">


    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputAppID">App Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="control-label">Stephen's Library</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputTableName">DB Connection</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="control-label">Stephen's Library DB Connection</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputTableName">DB Table Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="control-label"><%=entityDefDTO.getTableName()%></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputEntityName">Entity Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntityName" placeholder="ex. Book">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputEntityName">Entity Name Plural</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntityName" placeholder="ex. Books">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try using css like `font-weight: normal;`  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: Thanks ... tried this but it didn't work ... `<div class="col-sm-10" style="font-size: normal;"><label class="control-label">Stephen's Library</label></div>` ... Note: "font-size: x-large;" makes that text bigger, but "font-weight: normal;" has no effect ... any ideas why?

Comment: which font are you using?

Comment: @NishargShah The only CSS that is used by the project is this `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css` ... the body tag has  `font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;` and the label tag has `font-weight: 700;` ... turns out the font displayed is not actually "bold" but is "font-weight: 700" ... I was able to get the desired effect by adding `style = "font-weight:300" to the desired label.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
font-weight-bold
```

like:

App Name
            
                Stephen's Library

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 font-weight-bold" for="inputTableName">DB Connection</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="control-label">Stephen's Library DB Connection</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2  font-weight-bold" for="inputTableName">DB Table Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="control-label"><%=entityDefDTO.getTableName()%></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2  font-weight-bold" for="inputEntityName">Entity Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntityName" placeholder="ex. Book">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2  font-weight-bold" for="inputEntityName">Entity Name Plural</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEntityName" placeholder="ex. Books">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may put the class "font-weight-bold" for label on the left to be bold and the "font-weight-normal" for the value on the right to be regular (not bold).

```html
<p class="font-weight-bold">Bold text.</p>
<p class="font-weight-bolder">Bolder weight text (relative to the parent element).</p>
<p class="font-weight-normal">Normal weight text.</p>
<p class="font-weight-light">Light weight text.</p>
<p class="font-weight-lighter">Lighter weight text (relative to the parent element).</p>
<p class="font-italic">Italic text.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the that, it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<label for="Gender" class="fw-bold">Gender :</label>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After learning more, I see that the only CSS that is used by the project is this `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css` ...

For my problem text, the label tag has `font-weight: 700;` ... so it turns out the font displayed is not actually "bold" but has a high font weight.

I was able to get the desired effect by adding `style = "font-weight:300"` to the desired label.